# NDFA associated with language L

Tags: regular-languages, finite-automata, nondeterminism

Let A = $(Q, \Sigma, \delta, S, F)$ be a deterministic finite automaton associated with the language
$L \subseteq \Sigma^*$

> $L' = \{y \in \Sigma^*:\exists x\in L. |x| = |y|\}$
>
> $L \subseteq L'$

How do I show that there exist a NDFA associated with L' ?

Comment: What do you think? Where did you try? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: If you have a specific question regarding the wording of the problem or about concrete steps in your own attempts at solving the problem, feel free to edit accordingly and we can reopen the question. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/questions/594/the-return-of-the-homework-question) for a relevant discussion. If you are uncertain how to improve your question, why not ask around in [chat]?

Comment: Isn't the condition $L \subseteq L'$ superfluous? Or is it a statement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: Replace every transition labelled $a \in \Sigma$ with a transition labelled $\Sigma$.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a proof using the closure properties of regular languages. Let $\pi: \Sigma^* \to a^*$ be the monoid homomorphism defined by $\pi(u) = a^{|u|}$. I let you verify that
$L' = \pi^{-1}(\pi(L))$. Since regular languages are closed under homomorphisms and inverses of homomorphisms, $L'$ is regular.